# How do I turn off progressive rendering for sceneAfter only in Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are rendering some custom geometry in `scene`. However, we have a toggle to make it transparent, and in that case we render it in `sceneAfter` instead, so that other geometry can be seen through it.

The problem is that if it's in sceneAfter, progressive rendering makes it flicker - which doesn't happen while it's in `scene`, which I suppose never progressively renders. I don't want to turn off progressive rendering in general, but is there a way to turn it off only for `sceneAfter`?

Answer (score 0):

I got the following feedback: 
Neither `scene` / `sceneAfter` nor `overlays` are rendered progressively. Only the main models (coming from loaders) are rendered progressively. But, by definition, `scene` is rendered before the main models, while `sceneAfter` is rendered afterwards. 
Objects in `sceneAfter` will therefore only be rendered after the main models have been rendered completely, which can lead to flickering for smaller models (that can often but not always be rendered completely in a single progressive frame). There is no way to '*disable progressive rendering for sceneAfter*'. If the model is small enough, it's worth evaluating whether progressive rendering can be disabled in general, though.
`Overlays` are rendered after each progressive frame, so they should be a suitable place to render transparent objects.